# Visibility between classes in a "matrioska" package

Tags: java, package, visibility

I have the `A` class  in the `a` package.

After I have the `B` class in the `a.b` package. `B` contains the method `m()`.

I want to call `m()` *inside and only inside* class `A`. Precisely I don't want to set `m()` to be `public`.

Is it possible?

Sorry for the title. I've not found anything better.

Edit for clarify: `A` and `B` classes have to be used by a developer (they form an API) and inside `A` I have a private method that compute something that modify the `B` object, but this cannot be called by the developer. **There is any other relation between the `a` and `a.b` packages in addition to the fact that their corresponding folders are one inside the other?**

Edit2: class `A` contains a `List<B>`. `A` is the class that has to talk with the server, which responses with a value. `A` has to insert this value in every element in the list.

Comment: Are you saying you want `A` to have explicit knowledge of what's contained in a non-subclass, but not expose `m()` to anything other than `A`?

Comment: Is there some reason the method `m()` couldn't/shouldn't be in class `A`? It seems logical to me since that is the only place you need/want to use it

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, something like.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen In brief class `A` contains a `List<B>`. `A` is the class that has to talk with the server, which response with a value. `A` has to insert this value in every element in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless `A` subclasses `B` (and I wouldn't do that just for the sake of inheritance), there's basically no "special" relationship between `A` and `B`, so there's no way of doing this, I'm afraid.

What exactly do you need to protect against here? Is it just a matter of not trusting yourself or your colleagues not to call the method at the right time, or something stronger? You could potentially check the stack at execution time, although that's dangerous in terms of inlining etc potentially messing things up - and it *would* only be at execution time.

Comment: In brief `A` and `B` classes have to be used by a developer (they form an API) and inside `A` I have a private method that compute something that modify the `B` object, but this cannot be called by the developer. There is any other relation between the `a` and `a.b` packages in addition to the fact that their corresponding folder are one inside the other?

Comment: @Baduel: No, the hierarchy of the packages is irrelevant as far as Java is concerned.

Comment: Therefore my question will be never have a good answer. It means that I made a mistake in the design step. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this using reflection and a little bit of hacking but it's would be very bad to do it like that. 
I could recommend reading up more about access levels on

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

```
 Access Levels
 Modifier   Class   Package  Subclass World  
 public      Y      Y         Y        Y
 protected   Y      Y         Y        N
 no modifier Y      Y         N        N
 private     Y      N         N        N
```

Comment: Yes I know it. But the real question is: why I should use the `parent.son` package if there isn't any parental relation? Or this relation exists?

Comment: it is not parent in that sense, it's more like grouping of various classes that do similar stuff

Comment: So the answer to my bold question is: No there isn't ?

Comment: Bold question: There is any other relation between the a and a.b packages in addition to the fact that their corresponding folders are one inside the other? Your answer: you are doing it wrong. Please read carefully the question before answering.

Answer (score -1):

make m protected and make A extend B. will that work for your model?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't adopt this solution because there would a _logical_ error in my code.

Comment: you should have mentioned that in your question :-) Anyways, another way is to put A and B in the same package and make m have a package level visibility (default access). Other than that, there's no real way. Depending on your requirements, B could be a private inner class to A, but you need to define your requirements better